# Unable to send email to non verified email ids in AWS SES after production access

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services

I have successfully  set up AWS SES in my application .I am able to send emails to verified email ids . After production request ( granted request) ,still it asks me to verify TO email ids . 
I got confirmation mail and I am able to send email to non verified email ids through console .But when I try sending through API it says "AWS Error Message: Email address is not verified. " .
Note that my FROM  email id is verified .
Do I need to make any changed in code to handle Production access .??

Answer (score 0):

Now its fine .. There was mis match in region .Manually I changed using API to the region I set in my aws ses account .